# parse_str prepending ampersand to elements?

Tags: php

I've been playing around with cURL, and am trying to send an array through as POST variables. I've decided to use http_build_query to pass the string as expected:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($sendParams));
```

I have the receiving end simply `print_r`'ing the $_POST, so I can see what is being sent through.

However, I am getting an ampersand attached to all of the parent elements *after* the first, is this normal? I assume that parse_str is used by cURL when parsing the querystring, so here is a super-simplified example that also leads to the ampersands:

```
<?php
    $array = array('foo', array('bar' => array('baz' => array(1,2,3))), 'test' => array(2,3,4));
    parse_str(http_build_query($array), $vars);
    print_r($vars);
?>
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => foo [amp;1] => Array ( [bar] => Array ( [baz] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) ) ) [amp;test] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seem to have answered my own question... `parse_str` is confused by &, and I need to run `html_entity_decode` first, before parsing the querystring.