# PHP parse_str of URL query returns array keys with 'amp' in key name

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

Environment: Wordpress (latest) on test site on Host (JustHost), with PHP version 5.4.43.

Using parse_str on a URL query, the resulting array returns array key names of amp;keyname . Example code:

```
$querystring = "ie=UTF8&qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=sitename-20";
parse_str($querystring, $queryarray);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($queryarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [ie] => UTF8
    [amp;qid] => 1468851514
    [amp;sr] => 8-1
    [amp;keywords] => there
    [amp;tag] => sitename-20
)
```

Why is the 'amp;' in the key name?

Is this a PHP version issue (it seems to work OK in a EasyPHP local environment - version 5.4.24, but not on my test WP server on my hosting place)? Or am I confused (again)?

Comment: I'm running PHP 7 and I'm not having trouble with the `&amp;`s. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178598/parse-str-prepending-ampersand-to-elements, you have to run `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: Try this before parse_str: `html_entity_decode($querystring);`

Comment: html_entity_decode was the answer!  Huzzah !! Thanks to all !!  

(not sure how to mark that as the answer...but Thanks!)

Comment: for me, I replaced this line in curl code 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

with this
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params, '', '&'));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**&'amp;** must only be used when outputting URLs in HTML/XML data.

You can try use **html_entity_decode()**

```
$querystring = "ie=UTF8&qid=1468851514&sr=8-1&keywords=there&tag=sitename-20";
parse_str(html_entity_decode($querystring), $queryarray);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($queryarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that `$querystring` doesn't contain other encoded entities, you can use `html_entity_decode`, as @Hugo E Sachez suggests. 
But in some complex systems `$querystring` may come from a place that you don't have control of, and it may contain entities that were encoded on purpose as a safety measure, like `&quot;`, or `&lt;`, or `&gt;` etc...

So, if you decode all entities, and then parse data, and then somehow return this data to user, probably some unwanted `<script>` can be executed.
I assume it would be safer to replace only `&amp;` with `&`, and keep other entities encoded. 
Like this: `parse_str(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $querystring), $queryarray);`

Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That situation should only occur if you have data corruption. Either the string is entity encoded and `&amp;` may be present but any other potential entity is double-encoded (e.g. `&amp;quot;`) so decoding will be fine, or you have entities in your encoded query data that are unaffected by decoding `foo=bar&amp;baz=%26qux;` -> `foo=bar&baz=%26qux;` -> `['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => '&qux;']`. Never entity decode unless you know the data has been entity encoded.